# INSERT IGNORE for date while ignoring time

Tags: mysql

I'm inserting data that are unique for all three columns using INSERT IGNORE. How can I exclude the time and check the date if its unique with the other two columns below?

**Unique index for columns:** timestamp, action, value

**Time stamp format:** 2016-04-21 13:33:47

**My table sample:**

2016-04-21 13:33:47, send, email

2016-04-20 11:21:32, send, email

2016-04-19 17:32:65, send, email

**What I'm trying to do:**
If I try to insert the data below, it should be ignored because there's existing data for 2016-04-21, send, email.

*2016-04-21 19:33:47, send, email*

Comment: By the way, 2016-04-19 17:32:65 isn't a valid timestamp. I'm assuming the seconds is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The only way an `IGNORE` will work is if you have one or more columns in a `UNIQUE` index. In this case you need a `DATE` field that's derived from your `DATETIME`.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE my_emails ADD COLUMN sent_date DATE
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_sent_date ON my_emails (sent_date)
```

Then you can populate it:

```
UPDATE my_emails SET sent_date=DATE(sent_datetime)
```

With whatever those columns are. From that point forward you'll need to be sure you populate both fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 5.7.6 or higher, you can create a generated column with a unique index.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN timestamp_date DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE(timestamp)) STORED,
ADD UNIQUE (timestamp_date, action, value);
```

With an earlier version of MySQL, you'll need to add a column to store the date and use a trigger (available from version 5.0.2) to update it whenever you insert new records in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN timestamp_date DATE;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_table_name_date BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.timestamp_date = DATE(NEW.timestamp);

-- If you already have any data in the table, update it to add the date.
UPDATE table_name SET timestamp_date = DATE(timestamp_date);

ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD UNIQUE (timestamp_date, action, value);

INSERT INTO table_name(timestamp, action, value) VALUES
('2016-04-21 13:33:47', 'send', 'email'),
('2016-04-20 11:21:32', 'send', 'email'),
('2016-04-19 17:32:55', 'send', 'email');

-- 3 row(s) affected

INSERT INTO table_name(timestamp, action, value) VALUES
('2016-04-21 19:33:47', 'send', 'email');

-- Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2016-04-21-send-email' for key 'timestamp_date'
```

Comment: You need 5.7.8 in order to create that index: "Prior to MySQL 5.7.8, virtual columns cannot be indexed. As of MySQL 5.7.8, InnoDB supports secondary indexes on virtual columns." [CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Comment: @Paul Spiegel I can't test, I don't have 5.7.6. But my understanding is that **virtual** generated columns cannot be indexed but **stored** generated columns can.

Comment: You're right: "A stored column does require storage space and can be indexed." However -  Nice solution.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Spiegel. I like your solution too, as it happens. I wouldn't have thought of it but now I'm aware of it the concept should come in handy for more complicated conditional inserts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an INSERT SELECT statement with constant data from a dummy table. This way you can include a WHERE clause.

```sql
insert into actions (`timestamp`, action, value)
    select '2016-04-21 19:33:47', 'send', 'email'
    from (select 1) dummy
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from actions
        where action = 'send'
          and value  = 'email'
          and date(`timestamp`) = '2016-04-21'
    );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5882c/1

The data will only be inserted if the condition in the subquery does not have any matches.